# Stall during Ubuntu 13.04 Installation

Tags: installation

Hi, I use Virtual Machine to install Ubuntu 13.04 by iso file, when it comes to "retrieving file 40 of 102", it stall for a long time for at least 1 hour, whats the problem...?

Comment: Check your Internet connectivity.

Answer (score 0):

Click on the Player button and in Removable Devices option Disconnect the Network Adapter. Hope it will work!